# Does HTML body element has padding attribute?

Tags: css

Refering to Eric Meyer's Reset css, it sets `padding` for the `html` and `body` elements. But I cannot find anywhere in documentation that `html` and `body` tags have these properties? Am I making a mistake?

```
/* v1.0 | 20080212 */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "don't have these properties"? HTML and BODY can have padding just like other elements.

Comment: I was hoping that it will be documented somewhere. Else how could I find where tag has which attributes?

Comment: I think you may be confusing HTML attributes (like `href`, `src`, etc...) with css properties (`width`, `padding`, etc...).

Comment: Ah! are you saying that all HTML elements follow box model and thus all elements will have border, margin, padding?

Comment: Of course it is not going to be absolutely 100% accurate, but essentially yes. CSS can be applied to basically anything. You will notice small issues with it applying to things like `display:inline` vs. `display:block` though. `display:inline` elements do not accept width and height, but you can make it `inline-block`, things like that.

Comment: @ManuChadha - All elements have all properties that apply to the media type. e.g. for the screen media type, all the properties that screen rendering may use must be assigned to every element - there are no exceptions. See [CSS 2.2 6.1 Specified, computed, and actual values](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#value-stages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is more interesting than it might have seemed at first. I guess what you really want is to get proofs that aforementioned elements are block-level so that paddings and especially margins can be properly applied.

Well, let's kick off. On MDN `<html>` and `<body>` are not given in the corresponding lists of [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)- and [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)- level elements. If we go to html5 [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-body-element) we can learn that `<body>`'s Content Model is Flow Content (<strike>which roughly corresponds to the html4 "block-level" category as [MDN writes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)</strike> see @Alohci comments below) and `<html>`'s Content Model comprises

> A head element followed by a body element.

Now let's go to the CSS2 [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html). It defines block-level elements (boxes) as follows:

> Block-level elements are those elements of the source document that are **formatted visually as blocks** (e.g., paragraphs). **The following values of the 'display' property make an element block-level: 'block'**, 'list-item', and 'table'.

Generally, block-level elements participate in a block formatting context and this [fact](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow) allows us to set margins. Now we need to understand what makes `<html>` and `<body>` block-level elements technically. Well, it is pretty simple - all modern browsers define so called "user agent stylesheet" where you can easily find:

```
body {display: block;}
html {display: block;}
```

For example, in Mozilla Firefox you can get these styles via

```
view-source:resource://gre-resources/html.css
```

In Google Chrome these lines can be spotted right in the Developer Tools's Styles tab.

So, answering your question, paddings and especially margins can be applied to `<html>` and `<body>` elements because <strike>they fall into html5 Flow Content content model (html4 "block-level" category) by standard</strike> and to ensure needed behaviour and avoid some quirks they are explicitly set in "user agent stylesheet" to be block-level elements via `display: block;`.

**PS**. That's how I got it after reading quickly through the specs. My explanation may contain inaccuracies. If you spotted one - feel free to correct in the comments section.

Comment: "Flow Content (which roughly corresponds to the html4 "block-level" category as MDN writes)" - MDN is wrong on this point. Flow content includes most if not all the elements HTML 4.01 classified as inline-level. The elements which aren't flow content are the ones that appear only as children of one or a small number of parent elements. e.g. li, caption, tbody, td, source, figcaption etc.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed this divergence since on w3c <span> has "Flow Content" category too. But I just relied on MDN :) The topic is quite confusing. I suppose that in the end it all actually boils down to the "display: block;" property in the user-agent styles that actually makes <html> and <body> elements treated as block-level whereas  from spec's standpoint they remain kinda "undefined" in this regard. What do you think?

Comment: The html4.01 spec says "Certain HTML elements that may appear in BODY are said to be "block-level" while others are "inline" (also known as "text level")." but it doesn't explicitly define <body> as either of them.

Comment: They're not "undefined". The display property does not automatically inherit, so the `body` element would have the initial value for all normal elements, which is "inline" if it were not for the user-agent stylesheet.

Comment: The `html` element is slightly different though. When, as is almost always the case, it is the root element of the document, CSS has a special rule. In [Section 9.7 Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float', point 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) it says "...  if the element is the root element, 'display' is set according to ...[specified value = inline becomes computed value = block]", so the html element would be block level even without the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: ok, now it fits: html's prop. display is computed with "block" value since this is the root element which is intuitively correct and body's default "inline" usually becomes "block" due to user-agent styles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does through css. I don't know where you can find proper documentation but several developers use this property in tutorials.
Ex:https://html.com/attributes/body-topmargin/

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely apply padding and other css attributes on body or html. Be careful though as you will be changing the layout of the complete page.